# Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties Setting default log level to "WARN"

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark, I am using spark 2.1.0 with python 2.7, and it's not working. I've been searching for a week to find a solution to my problem without success.

I am getting following error when I run pyspark in commmadLine:

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/02/16 02:37:41 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.findHadoopBinary(HiveConf.java:2327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:105)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at py4j.reflection.CurrentThreadClassLoadingStrategy.classForName(CurrentThreadClassLoadingStrategy.java:40)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionUtil.classForName(ReflectionUtil.java:51)
        at py4j.reflection.TypeUtil.forName(TypeUtil.java:243)
        at py4j.commands.ReflectionCommand.getUnknownMember(ReflectionCommand.java:175)
        at py4j.commands.ReflectionCommand.execute(ReflectionCommand.java:87)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/02/16 02:38:21 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
17/02/16 02:38:21 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 179, in getOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
>>>
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 110, in killChild
    Popen(["cmd", "/c", "taskkill", "/f", "/t", "/pid", str(proc.pid)])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 236, in signal_handler
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning information "Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries."

I use Windows, in "Environment Variables", add a variable "HADOOP_HOME" with value of your hadoop directory path. For example, my hadoop install under c:\hadoop.
It would be "HADOOP_HOME" with value "c:\hadoop"

restart your cmd

At this time, if the warning information shows: "Could not locate executable c:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries."

You need to github download hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master.zip and copy winutils.exe to c:\hadoop\bin

At this time, it should work